# python code works (SELENIUM) but the data is repeated

Tags: python, selenium

I'm learning about selenium. I wrote some python code to scrape data from a website. It works but it only takes out the first repeated link and generates the csv. Is it not working because the code repeats the information from the first link?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import csv
# Specifying incognito mode as you launch your browser[OPTIONAL]
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")
lista_datos = []
resultado = []
# Create new Instance of Chrome in incognito mode
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\inspiron3420\Downloads\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=option)

# Go to desired website
browser.get("https://www.biobiochile.cl")

# Wait 20 seconds for page to load
timeout = 20
try:
    variable = 'incendio'
    boton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search-anchor']")
    boton.click()
    buscar = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='buscador-bbcl']/div/input")
    buscar.send_keys(variable)
    accion = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='buscador-bbcl']/div/span[2]/button")
    accion.click()

except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()

try:

    WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "resultados-texto")))
except:
    print ("Elementos no encontrados")
    #Obtenemos en una lista los elementos encontrados
resultados = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("resultados-texto")            
for resultado in resultados:
    titulopre = resultado.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='menu-buscador2']/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/div[2]/div[1]")
    titulo = titulopre.text
    fechapre = resultado.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='menu-buscador2']/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/div[2]/div[2]")
    fecha = fechapre.text
    #Finalmente metemos en una lista de listas los datos obtenidos
    lista_datos.append([titulo,fecha])
    csvsalida = open('scrappingbiobio.csv', 'w', newline='')
    salida = csv.writer(csvsalida)
    salida.writerow(['titulo', 'fecha'])
    salida.writerows(lista_datos)
    csvsalida.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
csvsalida = open('scrappingbiobio.csv', 'w', newline='')
```

have `w` which overide every time

you should use append,

```
csvsalida = open('scrappingbiobio.csv', 'a', newline='')
```

now the problem is it will write this row `salida.writerow(['titulo', 'fecha'])` every time. For that you can check file exist or not

```
import os

csvsalida = open('scrappingbiobio.csv', 'a', newline='')
    salida = csv.writer(csvsalida)
    if os.path.isfile('scrappingbiobio.csv') == False:
        salida.writerow(['titulo', 'fecha'])
    salida.writerows(lista_datos)
    csvsalida.close()
```